# Too late for the schedule

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.9, scheduler

When Cron with "newsletter_send_all" this job code execute then its status became missed and pass message like below. currently using magento's defalt cron settings with UTC time. My Cron.php executed in every 5 minute. Please help me out on this curios issue.

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule' in /home/test/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(293): Mage::throwException('Too late for th...')
    #1 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
    #2 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #3 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #4 /home/test/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
    #5 /home/test/public_html/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
    #6 {main}
```

Also made below modification in newslatter module's observer in core for testing purpose but still its not working

```
    public function scheduledSend($schedule)
    {
        $countOfQueue  = 1; // default 3 Modified on 14 Nov 17
        $countOfSubscritions = 1; //default 20 Modified on 14 Nov 17

        $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/queue')->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize($countOfQueue)
            ->setCurPage(1)
            ->addOnlyForSendingFilter()
            ->load();

        $collection->walk('sendPerSubscriber', array($countOfSubscritions));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> This happens when the scheduler finds pending jobs that were supposed
>   to be scheduled longer than the time configured in
>   'system/cron/schedule_lifetime'. By default this value is set to 15
>   minutes.
>
> There are two different problems the may result in you seeing this
>   error:
>
> 1. Cron isn't configured to run often enough: If you don't trigger cron
>      often enough then the tasks start piling up and most likely tasks
>      will be too late for schedule at the point when they're being
>      executed by the scheduler. Instead of increasing the
>      scheduler_lifetime settings you should increase the frequency cron
>      is being called to */5 * * * * (every 5 minutes) or even * * * * *
>      (every minute).
> 2. You have long running cron jobs that will block the execution of
>      other jobs: In case you're importing data, indexing products,
>      generating reports or doing other long-running jobs via cron (which
>      is generally a good idea) other jobs will not be run in parallel
>      (unless you're running cron.php instead of cron.sh). This will
>      result in these jobs not being executed. Find out which jobs are
>      preventing others from running (by looking at the timeline view) and
>      run them in a different cron group. (look at this for more
>      information and check the features added to version >0.5.0 for an
>      easier way to configure and manage cron groups.

source https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/doc/faq.md